# C - If statement inside While loop. Continuous Scanf()

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, floating-point, scanf

Well I want that this function returns me the change. And I have restrictions, I can't insert all types of coins. For example if I have `givemeChange(0.50)` I want to insert money until they are enough for pay the product. I can't find a solution. I insert 2 numbers in the terminal and then the function always go on `return 0.69`

This is my code:

Thank you for your time

```
float givemeChange(float price){

printf("Only these coins are allowed:\n" );
printf("0.05€ 0.10€ 0.20€ 0.50€ 1€ 2€\n\n");

float str = 0 ;
float count = 0 ;
while(count <= price){

  printf("Insert coins\n" );
  scanf("%f\n",&str );

  if(str == 0.05){
    count = count + 0.05;
  }
  if(str == 0.10){
    count = count + 0.10;
  }
  if(str == 0.20){
    count = count + 0.20;
  }
  if(str == 0.50){
    count = count + 0.50;
  }
  if(str == 1){
    count = count + 1;
  }
  if(str == 2){
  count = count + 2;
  }
  else{
  return 0.69;
  }
 }
  return (price-count);
}
```

Comment: You want `else if` in a lot of places.  Right now, if `str != 2`, you return 0.69, every time.

Comment: Print what you scan, or use a different debugging method of your choice, to see what happens.

Comment: You could run into troubles as usually, you cannot exactly store any number save powers of two - you cannot store e.g `0.5` exactly in memory since in the binary system, its a never ending fraction, like `1/3` in decimal. Thus you might have a hard time with your comparisons `==`. It's like `1.0 / 3.0 == 0.3333` will never be true no matter how many `3` you add at the decimal.

Comment: Yeah, I understood the error. Now I'm trying to find a solution . I put else for each if.

Comment: @MichaelBeer so what can I do ? I can't figure out a possible solution

Comment: @MichaelBeer You mean `0.2` or something, `0.5` can be represented exactly.

Comment: You have to remove the ```\n``` in the scanf.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: @Veltas This is a minimal part of my work. My homework consists of create a Client and a Server (done) using sockets an threads. I'm tired, it's late and I have to finish as soon as possible. I know this is easy, I know, I'm embarrassed but I asked for help because I can't find a solution.

Comment: Your tutor could so easily have avoided a lot of hassle by just insisting 'Don't use floating-point for this question' :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You run into troubles with your comparisons I guess:
In the binary system, for fractions only powers of 2 can be represented exactly - `0.2` cannot be represented exactly in the binary system, because in binary, it probably will be a never ending fraction.
you encounter the same in decimal with fractions like `1/3`, which is represented *roughly* by `0.33`, but you can never represent it exactly as decimal fraction. Thus you might have a hard time with your comparisons `==`. It's like (in our decimal system) `1.0 / 3.0 == 0.3333` will never be true no matter how many 3 you add at the decimal.

Instead comparing absolute values, you should resort back to checking whether your entered value is *close enough* to your target value like this:

```
...

float abs(float a) {return (a < 0) ? -a : a; }

const float epsilon = 0.005;

...

  printf("Insert coins\n" );
  scanf("%f",&str );

  if(abs(str - 0.05) < epsilon) {
      printf("Gave 0.05\n");
    count = count + 0.05;
  }

  if(abs(str - 0.10) < epsilon) {
      printf("Gave 0.10\n");
     count = count + 0.10;
  }

  ...
```

However, for your problem, it would probably easier (and adivable) to read in your values as strings, then you could compare them using `strcmp` to the expected values and treat them appropriately, like so:

```
 char  input[100];

 ...

 scanf("%100s", input);
 input[99] = '\0';

 if(0 == strcmp(input, "0.05")) {
    printf("You gave 0.05\n");
    count += 0.05;
 }

 /* and so on with the other options */
```

If you also want to accept inputs like `.5` or the likes, you would have to write your own compare function.

The solution is yours to pick, just for the sake of completeness, here's a tight solution that compiles straight away - went with a kind of lookup table to prevent all those `if's` to type...:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

float givemeChange(float price){

    struct {const char* input; float value;} input_map[] =
    {
        {"0.05", 0.05},
        {"0.10", 0.10},
        {"0.20", 0.20},
        {"0.50", 0.5}
    };

    printf("Only these coins are allowed:\n" );
    printf("0.05€ 0.10€ 0.20€ 0.50€ 1€ 2€\n\n");

    char input[100] = {0};
    float  count = 0 ;
    while(count <= price){

        printf("Insert coins\n" );
        scanf("%100s",input );
        input[99] = 0;

        for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(input_map) / sizeof(input_map[0]); ++i) {

            if(0 == strcmp(input_map[i].input, input)) {
                printf("Gave %s\n", input_map[i].input);
                count += input_map[i].value;
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    return count - price;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    printf("Your change %f\n", givemeChange(0.5));

}
```

Comment: Yes, definitely the second method is better. I'm trying, thank you so much

Comment: Thank you so much, It works like a charm! After 10 hours of programming I can go to sleep. I did an echo server and I can't do this thing, so embarrassing. You are a legend thanks